# IP changes while logging in to cpanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am trying to access my cpanel using godaddy. As I click on my cpanel, it asks me to sign in again, and when I sign in with my username and password, it shows "**You IP address has changed, please login again**". When I try to sign in again, it shows same error and I can't even login now. What might be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Just flush your DNS. For Windows, go to Power Shell as admin and run this command: ipconfig /flushdns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not cPanel issues. It's your ISP provider issues. You have dynamic IP from your ISP and due to that you are facing this issues, Please contact them about this OR get a static IP from them so that your connection IP Will not change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error like the one below when trying to access cPanel or your Webmail (on cPanel accounts), you most likely are using Internet provider which is providing you with dynamic IP address or with very quickly changing IP address.

If you are facing automatic Logout issue in cPanel, then here are three simple methods to resolve the issue:

1. Change your Internet connection/ISP
2. Resolve the issue from Root level/Hosting provider
3. TOR Browser

This is usually due to using some kind of proxy or VPN that changes your IP address every few seconds/minutes. Another reason might be if your ISP constantly changes your IP addresses.
How to resolve this issue?

First of all try to restart your router or Internet connection. Sometimes this can also do the work.
Another way is to reolve this issue fromk Root level. So if you are having root access then try to change the setting "Cookie IP validation" from Strict to Loose or you also also disable it completely in WHM's Tweak Settings,
Follow the steps given below if you have root access:

Step:1 Login into WHM.
Step:2 Go to ‘Server Configuration’.
Step:3 Click on ‘Tweak Settings’.
Step:4 Go to the tab ‘Security’.
Step:5 Locate the option ’Cookie IP Validation’.
Step:6 Change the settings to “Loose” and the frequency of re-authentication will be lowered. You can also be disabled it entirely.
Step:7 Disable proxy domains. If you do not perform this step, you have to utilize a proxy server with a static IP address to establish and maintain your connection.
Step:8 Click the button ‘Save’.
Problem Solved!!